# Nginx - how to serve protected video on a rendered page in Django, instead of a forced download?

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-views, nginx-location

I need a protected video file on a page rendered by Django. The file is protected, but it's not serving an html rendered page with the `<video src="...">` as I'd expect, ***like netflix.*** Instead, all I get is a jumbled mess like [this image.](https://ibb.co/1GmxrK7)

I know the internal redirect is serving the file, therefore it shows up like that, but I need it on a rendered page with the other html ***like netflix does***.... What am I doing wrong??

**Nginx conf file:**

```
location /secret_videos/ {
    internal;
    alias /home/username/path/to/secret/videos/;
}
```

**Url:**

```
path('protected_video/', views.protected_video, name='protected_video'),
```

**View:**

```
def protected_video(request):
    ....
    if request.method =='POST':
        if some_var == 'the_correct_value':
            protected_uri = '/secret_videos/secret-vid-1.mp4'
            response = render(request, 'template.html', {'some_var ': True, 'protected_uri': protected_uri})
            response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = protected_uri
            return response
    return render(request, 'template.html', {})
```

**Template, but it's not rendering html, only the image above:**

```
<video width="75%" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="{{ protected_uri }}" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser doesn't support the mp4 video format.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining what should be two request/responses: rendering the page, and sending the video.

You need to render the template, in which you give the video a URL that calls a Django view. That second view then returns a response with the secret URL as the accel-redirect. So:

```
path('protected_video/', views.protected_video, name='protected_video'),
path('video_url/<slug: video_slug>/', views.redirect_to_video, name='redirect_to_video'),

...
def protected_video(request):
    ....
    if request.method =='POST':
        if some_var == 'the_correct_value':
            protected_uri = reverse('redirect_to_video' , kwargs={'video_slug': 'some_slug'})
            return render(request, 'template.html', {'some_var ': True, 'protected_uri': protected_uri})

def redirect_to_video(request, slug):
    ... some logic to get the secret URL from the slug ...
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = secret_url
    return response
```

Comment: BOOYAH! ᕙ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ᕗ Thanks!!